# Tensorflow ValueError on session.run with batch training

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm training a RNN similar to the one in tensorflow tutorial, for sequential data. The data is [batch_size, step, dimension], and labels is [batch_size, num_classes].

Since sequence length is different for different samples, I would like to create batch training -- at each time I grab 32 samples data, padded them into the the longest sequence size and then fed them into rnn graph for training.

The data is defined as:

```
data = DataGenerator(data_path, label_path)
train_data, train_label, train_seqlen, test_data, test_label = data.train_test_data(0.2)    
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, None, num_dim])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, num_classes])
seqlen = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size])
model = VariableSeqModel(x, y, seqlen)
```

Train_data is [batch_size, step, dim], train_label is [batch_size, num_classes].
Seqlen is [batch_size,1] for recording the actual sequence length of samples in each batch. Is that correct that I define x as [batch_size, None, num_dim] for variable sequence length?

After defining the RNN and data structure, launching the session as in this code sample:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    step = 1
    while step*batch_size < 1000:
        batch_xx, batch_y, batch_seqlen = data.next(batch_size, train_data, train_label, train_seqlen)
        batch_x = data.batch_padding(batch_xx,batch_seqlen)
        sess.run(model.optimize, feed_dict={x: batch_xx, y: batch_y, seqlen: batch_seqlen})

        step += 1
```

I hit upon the following ValueError (stacktrace below):

```
dynamic_rnn.py in <module>()
--> 129  sess.run(model.optimize, feed_dict={x: batch_xx, y: batch_y, seqlen: batch_seqlen})

tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    708    try:
    709    result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 710   run_metadata_ptr)
    711    if run_metadata:
    712    proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    879   ' to a larger type (e.g. int64).')
    880 
--> 881   np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
    882 
    883   if not subfeed_t.get_shape().is_compatible_with(np_val.shape):

numpy/core/numeric.pyc in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    480 
    481 """
--> 482 return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    483 
    484 def asanyarray(a, dtype=None, order=None):

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I am stumped at this point. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Simply declare `seqlen = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])` and it works good. "[None]" here indicates the dynamic tensor type of batch size and the batch_size is simply tf.int32.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but it seems to me that the problem is here

> Seqlen is [batch_size,1]

As the tensorflow tutorial suggests , sequence length should be

> sequence_length: (optional) An int32/int64 vector sized [batch_size].

You may try by populating your seqlen array accordingly.
Hope this will help.